# Magento Connect: Release not created

Tags: magento-connect

I'm getting the following error message while trying to upload a new version of my extension to Magento Connect:

> An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect: Release not
>   created.

This occurs while trying to upgrade a M1 extension in the way that I have always done it. This error has been constant for the last few days and happens after uploading the .tgz file.

Has any one else seen this error and does anyone know what causes it? Could it be an issue on Magento's end and if so, who would I contant about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change .tgz file name so it contains package name and version.

Example:

Package name: **My_Good_Module**

Version: **1.8.0**

.tgz file name:

**My_Good_Module-1.8.0.tgz**



Package name and version you can find in the package.xml file.
That is located inside the .tgz archive.